# Write to flash drive with fopen

Tags: c, linux

I have a pendrive at `/dev/sdc`.

I want to write a simple file-system to it. How would I open this as file? It is possible to open with `fopen`?

I've tried to clear it but no bytes are returned.

```
while (fgetc(device) != EOF) {
    fputc(0, device);
}
```

Comment: You might possibly be able to open it with `fopen()`, but for your purposes, it would probably be more appropriate to open it with `open()`, and generally to use the POSIX file-descriptor-based I/O functions instead of C stdio functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger how would I write as binary to a `open` file?

Comment: The file-descriptor based I/O functions provide *only* binary I/O.  The primary function from that group for writing data is the aptly-named [`write()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

Comment: Thank-you very much. Please submit a question so I can mark as solved.

Comment: Note that the fragment of code attempts to read a character from the device and then attempts to overwrite the next character (presumably) with a null byte.  Even assuming the file is open in read/write mode, you have to use a positioning operation (`fseek()` or `rewind()` or similar) when you switch between reading and writing _and_ when you switch between writing and reading.  At minimum, you'd need `fseek(device, 0, SEEK_CUR);` before and after the `fputc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is possible that you could open the device file with `fopen()` and use C stdio functions to manipulate it, it would probably be more appropriate for your purpose to open it with POSIX `open()` (thus obtaining a file descriptor rather than a `FILE *`) and to thereafter operate on it with the POSIX file-descriptor-based I/O functions, such as `write()` and `read()`.  These provide an inherently binary interface to the file, without any library-level buffering other than what you provide yourself, and on Unix-like operating systems they are more conventional than C stdio functions for low-level operations such as you are proposing.